# HTML Table align images and text

Tags: html

In a sample article I added a html table widh 2 columns, left column for images and right column for image descriptions.

The problem is, the text description on the right column is below the images, it´s like the images are forcing the text to break into another line.

this is a sample code as I used:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Image.jpg</td>
<td>Image.jpg description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image2.jpg</td>
<td>Image2.jpg description</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can see the problem here [On this page](http://sharkpt.com/aprender-a-jogar)

Answer (score 8):

You just have to add `style="vertical-align:top"` to `td`

Or `vertical-align:middle` if you'd like to position the text in the middle of the row

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS in the text `<TD>`:

```
vertical-align:top;
```

i.e.:

```
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
   Trio: Quaisquer três cartas do mesmo valor. Este exemplo ...
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

So to understand you want the photo and the text to align correct? Can you use a valign attribute?

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">January</td>
 <td valign="top">$100</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td valign="bottom">February</td>
 <td valign="bottom">$80</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Top, Bottom and Center should be used depending on how you want it to align.

Comment: That will probably work, but I think most web designers would prefer to manage the alignment in CSS.  Doesn't make your answer wrong though!